# Setting the position of TKinter labels?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a program, where I place a label in the bottom left and bottom right corners of my window. My code is as follows:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x250")
var = StringVar()
label = Label( root, textvariable=var)

var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")
label.place(x=20, y=60)
label.pack()
root.configure(background='lightyellow')
root.mainloop()
```

For some reason, when I do so, the label does not change at all. I am new to TKinter, so I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling `pack` immediately after calling `place`? Use one or the other. When you use both, only the second one has any effect.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would use .grid if at all possible.  Put labels in lower left and lower right cells.  Using .place:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x250")
ll = tk.Label(root, text='lower left')
lr = tk.Label(root, text='lower right')
##ll.place(x=0, y=250, anchor='sw')
##lr.place(x=1000, y=250, anchor='se')
ll.place(relx=0.0, rely=1.0, anchor='sw')
lr.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor='se')
#root.mainloop()
```

With absolute x,y placing, labels do not move if window is resized.  With relative placing, they do.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `pack()` along with `place()`. From what I have seen pack overrides `place()` and just sticks in all the labels in the middle of the frame from top to bottom. Just get rid of `pack()` and it should work.